# Why do some websites hijack "open in new tab"?

Tags: interaction-design, web-app, browser, default, behavior-design

Just came across this annoyance reading an article at `time.com`. Unfortunately, this was not the first time I experience this, and I have a strong feeling it won't be the last.

Leaving aside discussions on whether this is horrible or not (hint: it often is), is there an actual reasoning why some websites break the middle click functionality, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click, and other mechanisms aimed to open hyperlinks in new tabs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's unlikely that there's intentional malice. There are times when "new tab" functionality is intentionally violated, usually because the website is written as a "single page application" (SPA). SPAs tend to load resources via JavaScript, but *competent* programmers will include a fallback URL so the page loads in a new tab or window correctly.

Whenever you find a site that doesn't behave this way, it's usually because the developers were either too inexperienced, too rushed, or too underpaid. As an example, I don't know what happened to Time's website, but it has **20 errors** just to *load* the page. That's unacceptable by most normal standards, but it's clear that Time hasn't put the resources necessary in to their online presence.

As a designer, there's not much to do here. Just design the best UI you can. If you're in QA, and you find that "Open in new tab" is broken, open a defect and send that back to the developers. And, of course, if you're a developer, test your own work before you send it to your QA, because a publicly broken website is a reflection on how much you care about your job.

Comment: Good point. Didn't think of this, even though I remember working on a client webapp which didn't work reliably if user had more than one tab open.